# Integral Question: $ I=\int_0^2 x^3\times(x^4\times(-1))^3 dx $- How to resolve it?

Tags: integration

What is the best way to solve:

$$
I=\int_0^2 x^3\times(x^4\times(-1))^3 dx
$$

Comment: Are you asking about $$\int_0^1 dx \, x^3 (x^4-1)^3$$

Comment: @Student, can you please confirm the edit

Comment: Yes, but im new on this website, so i dont know how to use symbols yet. Thank You!

Comment: I hope that's what you meant. Search for "LaTeX" on Google, any doubts post [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Put $x^4=u$ so that $4x^3dx=du$

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading your expression correctly, it simplifies to $\int_0^2 (x^3)(-x^{12})\,dx$, and then to $\int_0^2 (-x^{15})\,dx$. Now the integration is easy.

Comment: If the integration is easy, why don't you finish it then? :)

Comment: Because this is likely to be homework-related, and I prefer to leave something for the student to do. As it is, I somewhat regret not writing Hint: $(x^4\times (-1))^3=-x^{12}$.

Comment: I didn't even know one could (perhaps it's "should") post such specific questions. Shouldn't they be closed as "not applicable to a larger audience" or edited so they are applicable?